# How is expectation of $x^2$ at time $t$ calculated?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

Ehrenfest theorem for position operator states

$$\frac{d\left<x \right>}{dt} = \left<[H,x]\right> + \left<\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right>$$

where $H = \frac{p^2}{2m}$ and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = 0$. Which gives

$\frac{d\left<x \right>}{dt} = \frac{\left<p\right>}{m}$

as $\left<[H,x]\right> = -\frac{i\left<p\right>}{m}$, which allows us to get

$\left<x(t)\right> = \left<x_0\right> + \frac{\left<p\right>}{m}t$

My question is, how is the value $\left<x^2(t)\right>$ calculated? Do we take $x(t) = x_0 + \frac{p}{m}t$ and square it or do we apply $\frac{d\left<x^2 \right>}{dt} = \left<[H,x^2]\right> + \left<\frac{\partial x^2}{\partial t}\right>$ and proceed as before? The reason I ask is that I am getting different answers for the two approaches. I feel that the second approach is correct, but the correct answer is coming by using the first method. My answer from the second method seems to be missing a term of $\frac{\left<p^2\right>}{m^2}t^2$, only giving

$\left<x^2(t)\right> = \left<x^2_0\right> + \frac{t}{m}\left<xp+px\right>$

and the only assumption I have taken is that $\left<\frac{\partial x^2}{\partial t}\right> = 0$. Is that wrong to assume? Where am I going wrong?

Edit: the $\frac{\left<p^2\right>}{m^2}t^2$ term is needed because the relation

$\left<\Delta x(t)\right>^2 = \left<\Delta x(0)\right>^2 + \frac{\left<\Delta p(0)\right>^2}{m^2}t^2 + \left<\Delta x(0)\Delta p(0) + \Delta p(0)\Delta x(0)\right>\frac{t}{m}$

has been used in too many papers to be wrong (for example, section 2.1 of paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.01083). The term $\frac{\left<\Delta p(0)\right>^2}{m^2}t^2$ only appears if the term $\frac{\left<p^2\right>}{m^2}t^2$ is present in $\left<x^2(t)\right>$.

PS: all this is being done for a free mass wave function

Comment: Usually one uses $\langle x^2\rangle$ to mean the mean/expectation of $x^2$, rather than the square of the mean (which would be $\langle x\rangle^2$), no?

Comment: Which is why I feel that the second approach is correct. However, if the operator x(t) itself can be defined as in the first method, maybe taking x^2(t) and then taking expectation value is valid. But then, there is no reason for the answer from the second method to be different.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why do you think $\langle x^2 \rangle$ needs to have the $t^2$ term you write?

Comment: d_b justification added in the post

Comment: That equation is for the variance of $x$, not for $\langle x^2\rangle$

Comment: And the equation for the variance of x is $\left<x^2\right>-\left<x\right>^2$ for which you need to know $\left<x^2\right>$, which is what I'm asking.

Comment: I know, just making sure you were aware :)

Answer (score 1):

$\def\dp{\dot p} \def\dx{\dot x} \def\ddx{\ddot x} 
\def\D#1#2{{d#1 \over d#2}} \def\DD#1#2{{d^2#1 \over d#2^2}}
\def\avg#1{\langle #1 \rangle}$ 
I can't follow your derivations, mainly because you don't state the meaning of your symbols. However for a free particle there's no need of Ehrenfest theorem. Heisenberg picture is recommended. Then
$$\dx = {p \over m} \qquad \dp = 0$$
$$\ddx = 0.$$

$$\D{}t\,{x^2} = {1 \over m}\,(x\,p + p\,x)$$
$$\DD{}t\,{x^2} = {2 \over m}\,p^2$$
$${d^3 \over dt^3}\,x^2 = 0.$$

We have shown that $x^2$ is a polynomial in $t$ of the second degree:
$$\avg{x^2} = \avg{x^2}_0 + {1 \over m}\,\avg{x\,p + p\,x}_0\,t + 
{1 \over m}\,\avg{p^2}\,t^2$$
where $\avg{\ldots}_0$ is computed at $t=0$. Also note that $p$ is a constant of the motion, so $\avg{p^n}$ doesn't depend on $t$, for all $n$.